# Do I have to Upgrade WordPress to "pro" if I want to edit the CSS?

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I started using WordPress just a few hours ago because I need to develop a couple of blogs to a client. I understand that WordPress is the best solution if you want something fast but flexible. But, the first thing that I wanted to do was just change the font of the post and I didn't find how to do it (for all the posts, because I changed it on this one using the HTML editor). I've read something about editing the CSS, but it turns that I need to buy the Pro upgrade to be able to use the custom design.

Is this the same if I use WordPress in my server?

I need someone to guide me on this one. I need WordPress as customizable as it can be. But, I prefer not to pay! :) Unless that's the only way to do it.

Comment: Try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com. SO is for programming questions, not about the features included in your WP installation. In the WP admin interace you can go to Appearance -> Editor -> and modify `styles.css` to modify your site.

Comment: This question is not about programming. I made this question long time ago with no correct understanding of what would be suitable for the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use WordPress on your own server, you can do anything you like to it - it's open source. The "Pro" upgrade is just for WordPress blogs hosted on the commercial WordPress.com platform.

Do note that running your own installation means you're responsible for adding plugins, themes, keeping the code up-to-date, etc. That has a cost too, even if it's not money directly out of your pocket.

Comment: And what do you recommend? Because it seems pretty comfortable to use it directly from the wordpress.com platform. If I upgrade my account, do you think I'm going to have enough to customize and build themes? And if I install it on my server, still going to be fast to get it working or its going to be more like a framework (like cakePHP).

Comment: Upgrading your server and the time/effort of keeping it up-to-date probably is going to cost you more than just paying a yearly fee to WordPress.com. WordPress is famously easy to *install*, though.

Comment: So, you're saying that if I upgrade I'm going to be able to fully customize the blogs?

Comment: There are still things you're never going to be on WordPress.com hosting. You won't be able to install totally new themes, you won't be able to install your own plugins, etc. If all you need to do is tweak CSS, though, it may be a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using wordpress on your own server - you are free to do anything with it. The best way to customize your site then is using a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). It will contain your customization, overriding styles from previously loaded parent theme (and/or adding some scripts). You will be able to upgrade parent theme then without loosing your customization (until parent theme owners deprecate something you use, but it must not happen often). There are some plugins for simplifying working with it as well. There are also some easier customization ways, if you want just minor changes - such as [Custom CSS in Jetpack plugin](http://jetpack.me/support/custom-css/), which works in similar way, as far as I know.

If you're using a wordpress.com account, you have less freedom in modifying things, consider using paid custom CSS plugin maybe. Or maybe mentioned above jetpack will do.

Also, as mentioned in other answers - there are [wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/), [wordpress.org forums](https://wordpress.org/support/), and [wordpress stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/), they seem to be better place for such questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you do not have to pay to customize CSS.  Check your server installation... particularly in the folder `$wordpress_install_home/wp-content/themes/default`.

You should have access to all the CSS files in there.

Comment: His blog is on WordPress.com currently, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

In your wordpress admin section of your site (usually www.yourdomain.com/wp-admin) on the left hand side nav bar, you will find a section called "appearance", if you expand this and click "editor" you can edit all of the files that your current theme uses.  A quick warning, if you are doing this on a live server, the changes you make are live as soon as you save them!!

Hope this helps